# php preg_match. Add to array

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

Basically I'm attempting to use preg_match to find all links with a PDF attachment and then add the entire url to an array. The part I'm struggling with is how to select everything before the match, upto the "quotes" of the `<a href="">`. I want to do this so that I can loop through the array and do whatever I need to with each document. I just want to end up with `'1234.pdf'` (plus any sub directory info) in the array.

Any ideas?

This is what I have so far, it only returns the match...

```
$string1 = "<a href='1234.pdf'>Document 1</a>";

$match = preg_match("/.pdf/i", $string1, $output);
```

Thanks

Comment: Note that `.` will not just match the full stop character but also any other (except line breaks); escape it to only match the `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a DOM parser to extract that information, because it's easier, and it's safer. Then you can use `preg_match` to check if the link is actually a PDF or not:

```
$html = '<a href="foo.pdf">Foo</a>'.
        '<a href="bar.jpg">Bar</a>'.
        '<a href="baz.pdf">Baz</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$result = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
   $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
   if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $href)) $result[] = $href;
}

print_r($result);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo.pdf
    [1] => baz.pdf
)
```

Comment: +1 for actually providing an example of correct php DOM traversal techniques.

Comment: Absolutely perfect. This is first time I've come across `DOMDocument`. Very useful, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should really use a proper HTML parser (see netcoder's answer) and apply an XPath expression to solve this.  If you are bound and determined to use a regex, try something like this:

```
$match = preg_match_all("/(?<=href=['\"])([^'\"]*\\.pdf[^'\"]*)(?=['\"])/",
                        $string1, $output);
```

Comment: This will match anything that is surrounded by some quotes.

Comment: @Gumbo: True.  I have adjusted the regex to at least require the `href=` prefix, but this is admittedly a very bad way to approach this.  I am only supplying a fall-back regex in case the OP doesn't follow the much better approach of using a proper HTML parser.  You can only make a regex like this perform so well...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you need to use sub-patterns.  Try something like this....

```
$match = preg_match("/href=\"(.*\.pdf)\"/i", $string1, $output);
```

The $output variable should be an array with index 0 containing full text matches and index 1 containing the text matched from between the parenthesis.